# Measuring voltage between two points

Tags: voltage, voltage-measurement

I Have the following Schematic:

[image: Schematic of Two batteries]

The book i am using ask for \$V_{BC}\$ which I found by \$V(B) - V(C) = 0V - 9V = -9V\$

The book gives the answer as 9V, is it safe to assume that since voltage is similar to pressure, we cant have negative pressure so I can take the modulus of my result and it would be equal to the 9V would this be allowed ?

Comment: Voltage is only a little similar to pressure. You need to understand what it is, including how does voltage behave with conductors, voltage sources and isolators.

Comment: Use V(final) - V(initial), in this case V(C) - V(B). It is very common to make sign mistakes when doing circuit analysis. Be careful.

Comment: @EugeneSh., then why do we call the base-emitter voltage of an BJT \$v_{be}\$ instead of \$v_{eb}\$? I've always seen the convention that \$v_{ab} = v_a - v_b\$. I think OP's book just has a typo or error in its solution.

Comment: @ThePhoton Hm. Looks like you are right and I am too rusty at this theory...

Comment: The convention definitely is \$V_{AB}=V_A-V_B\$, and the book is wrong.

Comment: @klamb the Book in question is "Practical Electronics for inventors 4th Edition"